Do linear operators on test function space always extend to distribution space?
When we extend the definition of operator $T:C_c^\infty(U)\to C_c^\infty (V)$ from classical setting to distribution space $D'(U)\to D'(V)$, if we can find a $T':C_c^\infty(V)\to C_c^\infty(U)$ such that $\int_V(Tf)g=\int_Uf(T'g)$ for all $f\in C_c^\infty(U),g\in C_c^\infty(V)$, then $\langle Tf,g\rangle:=\langle f,T'g\rangle$ for $f\in D'(U),g\in C_c^\infty(V)$ defines the extension $T:D'(U)\to D'(V)$ that we need.
My question is, is this method of finding $T'$ always possible? Is there $T:C_c^\infty(U)\to C_c^\infty (V)$ such that the adjoint $T':C_c^\infty(V)\not\to C_c^\infty (U)$?

No, this method is not always possible. Below is an example of a continuous linear map $T:C_c^\infty(U)\to C_c^\infty(V)$ whose transpose $T':D'(V)\to D'(U)$ does not map $C_c^\infty(V)$ to $C_c^\infty(U)$.

First choose some nonzero $h\in C_c^\infty(V)$ and for every $f\in C_c^\infty(U)$ and every $v\in V$, let
$$Tf(v)=\biggl(\int_Uf(u)\,du\biggr)h(v).$$
This defines a continuous linear map $T$ from $C_c^\infty(U)$ to $C_c^\infty(V)$. However, for every $f\in C_c^\infty(U)$, we have
$$\langle T'\overline h,f\rangle=\langle\overline h,Tf\rangle=\int_V\overline{h(v)}\biggl(\int_Uf(u)\,du\biggr)h(v)\,dv=\int_U\biggl(\int_V|h(v)|^2\,dv\biggr)f(u)\,du,$$
which shows that $T'\overline h\notin C_c^\infty(U)$ even though $\overline h\in C_c^\infty(V)$.

Interestingly, this particular $T$ above cannot be extended into a continuous linear map from $D'(U)$ to $D'(V)$. More generally, there is the following result.

Let $T$ be a continuous linear map from $C_c^\infty(U)$ to $C_c^\infty(V)$. The following assertions are equivalent:

there exists a continuous linear map $S$ from $D'(U)$ to $D'(V)$ which extends $T$,
the transpose $T'$ of $T$ maps $C_c^\infty(V)$ to $C_c^\infty(U)$.


You already know about 2 $\Rightarrow$ 1: the extension $S$ is given by letting $SF=F\circ T'$ for every $F\in D'(U)$. Conversely, suppose now that 1 holds. I will show that $T'$ coincides on $C_c^\infty(V)$ with the transpose $S'$ of $S$, which will prove 2 (recall that the space $C_c^\infty(U)$ is reflexive, which allows to identify $D'(U)'$ with $C_c^\infty(U)$).
For every $g\in C_c^\infty(V)$ and every $f\in C_c^\infty(U)$, we have
$$\langle T'g,f\rangle=\langle g,Tf\rangle=\langle Tf,g\rangle=\langle Sf,g\rangle=\langle f,S'g\rangle=\langle S'g,f\rangle.$$
This shows that $T'g=S'g$ for every $g\in C_c^\infty(V)$.

Oh yes, the trick of rank 1 operator! I forgot to use this.
